# JSF 2.2 Flows and Tomcat 7 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Context

Tags: java, spring, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2.2

I try to get familiar with the new jsf 2.2 features like page flows. So I did my Project within Tomcat 7 and the help of Spring.

Everything works fine until I added the first flow configuration and try to access the flow.
I am pretty sure I have a missing dependency but what kind of.

I got the following Stacktrace within the call:

```
Sep 05, 2013 6:03:34 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl 
log 1100: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Context 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Context
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2627)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1432)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1310)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.pushFlow(FlowHandlerImpl.java:374)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.transition(FlowHandlerImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.clientWindowTransition(FlowHandlerImpl.java:321)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:270)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
```

I have the following dependencies described in my pom file

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSR-330 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

maybe someone knows how to deal with tomcat spring and jsf 2.2.

A maybe this could be helpful as well:
I did not add anything to tomcat lib folder,I just add all jsf jars to the web archive, but that should make no difference, because the class is missing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF is slowly moving to CDI as to bean management. The new JSF 2.2 `@FlowScoped` annotation is CDI based. CDI is part of Java EE Web Profile. This is out the box provided by true Java EE containers such as [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org), [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net), [JBoss AS/EAP](http://jboss.org), [WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/software/websphere/), [WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/us/appserver/), [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/resin-application-server/), etc, but not by barebones JSP/Servlet containers such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) and [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Spring is essentially a full competitor of Java EE (CDI/EJB/JPA/JSF). You seem to have chosen for Tomcat+Spring instead of a real Java EE container. If you want to stick to Spring for some unclear reason, then you should be using [Spring Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow) instead of JSF Flow scope.

But if you're open to replacing Tomcat+Spring, then you can also just replace it altogether by one of the aforementioned Java EE containers. They will provide CDI/EJB/JPA (and JSF) out the box. You can if necessary easily upgrade their bundled JSF implementation to the desired Mojarra 2.2.2 version. The exact instructions depends on the container used.

An alternative would be to install CDI in Tomcat. Weld (the CDI reference implementation) has a guide on exactly that subject: [Application servers and environments supported by Weld](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html).

Comment: thanks for your description, i know spring web flow, as well as the ee technology, but i like to check out new technologies as I described in the question already. I do not agree with the description of an unclear reason in putting spring and tomcat together, I know the religious question about EJB vs Spring from both sides and in my opinion it is just a question of requirements, but thats getting to far now. I will test the integration of weld, so thank you for that advise.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of JSF expect a, more or less, full Web Profile to be available and tomcat isn't providing that. To be exact it is missing the CDI api, next to that you probably need a CDI implementation active (like Weld or the likes).

Some information in [this forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/228085?start=0&tstart=0) post on the JBoss website.